# Get radio button value and trigger click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have **2 radio buttons** with two different values and **a button**. Radio buttons are such as, one with **value 2** and one with **value 4**.

*This is my radio buttons:*

```
<input type="radio" value="2" name="match[rounds]" id="match_rounds_2">
<input type="radio" value="4" name="match[rounds]" id="match_rounds_4">
```

*This is my button:*

```
<a id="clickme">Click me</a>
```

What I am looking for is to get *"chosen"* radio button value and based on which radio button/value that has been chosen trigger click.

If user choose, radio button with **value 2**, trigger **1 click**, if choose, radio button with **value 4**, trigger **2 clicks**.

Comment: Seems like you are asking for wrong approach ? What exactly is expected output ?

Comment: Output is trigger click based on which radio buttons that has been clicked/chosen. My link is for my nested form and I want to make 1 nested form or 2 based on the clicks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi kindly check this https://jsfiddle.net/n2njbt9b/  i hope this is what you wanted...

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#match_rounds_2,#match_rounds_4 ').on('change', function(){
    if($('#match_rounds_2').is(':checked'))
    {
        $('#clickme').trigger('click');
    }
    if($('#match_rounds_4').is(':checked'))
    {
        $('#clickme').trigger('dblclick');
    }
  });

  $('#clickme').on('click', function(){
    alert ('clicked'); // Click logic
  });

  $('#clickme').on('dblclick', function(){
    alert ('double clicked'); // Double Click logic
  });
});
```

Comment: Tnx, This works good, but instead of alert, how can I make/trigger actual click and double click?

Comment: @Rubioli I am actually triggering click and double click... just replace the alert statement with your logic

Comment: single click works fine, but double clicks is not make/triggered.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by writing following code.

```
$('#clickme').on('click', function(){
 var v =  $('input[name=match[rounds]]:checked').val();
})
```

Comment: Tnx @Ejaz Karim. How does it trigger 1 or 2 clicks?

Comment: What does it mean by trigger 1 or 2 clicks? Do you mean double click or single click?

Comment: yes, If choosen radio button value = 2, single click or if choosen radio button value = 2, double click.

Comment: I think what you're trying to do is not good solution. I don't know about your problem but it seems like it is NOT proper way to do it.

Comment: I know, its a temporary solution for now. Any solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

```js
// get some dom elements
var $radios = document.getElementsByName('match[rounds]');
var $button = document.querySelector('#clickme');
var $log = document.querySelector('#log');

// dispatch event by name on element
var dispatch_event = function(el, eventName){
  el.dispatchEvent(new Event(eventName));
}

// debugging: add some logs to show exact clicks
var add_log = function(root, log_string){
  var $new_log = document.createElement('li');
  $new_log.textContent = log_string;
  root.appendChild($new_log);
};
                             
// iterate over all $radios elements
[].forEach.call($radios, function(el) {
    
    // bind event
    el.onchange = function(event){
      
      // get value
      var value = event.target.value;

      // value is the radio.value property, 
      // when 2, t trigger 1 click
      if(value == 2){
        
        // trigger event 1 time
        dispatch_event($button, 'click');
      } else if (value == 4) {
        
        // 2 times
        dispatch_event($button, 'click');
        dispatch_event($button, 'click');
      }
    }
});

// the button that must be clicked
// for demo, we just log it
// YOU HAVE TO MAKE YOUR OWN LOGIC HERE
$button.onclick = function(){
  add_log($log, 'clicked');
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" value="2" name="match[rounds]" id="match_rounds_2">
<input type="radio" value="4" name="match[rounds]" id="match_rounds_4">

<a id="clickme">Click me</a>

<ul id="log"></ul>
```

Comment: Tnx, This works great, Instead of log how can make/trigger single and double click on the #clickme button?

Comment: Click is already triggered, `dispatch_event($button, 'click');` this is calling click event, you just need to add your logic into `$button.onclick`

Comment: Thanks, Im dummy when it comes to javascript/jQuery. I did this: `$button.onclick = function(){
    $( "#clickme" ).click();
  }` Is it correct?